# In serial communication, is the RX pin pulled high by default?

Tags: arduino, serial

I would like to establish one way uart serial communication between an Arduino 5V and an ESP32 3.3V module.
The communication would be ESP32 TX pin ---> Arduino RX pin
I wouldn't use the second serial line, since I only need to transmit one way.

Now my question is, does the arduino pull its RX pin to high at any time during the serial communication?

If I understand serial correctly, the device only manipulates it's own TX pin, but leaves its own RX pin floating, is that correct?
The reason I need to know is that ESP32 is not 5V tolerant, so I need to make sure the arduino won't pull its RX pin high at some point and fry my poor ESP32.

Comment: I'm gonna guess it depends on the type of serial communication. Do you, by any chance, mean RS232/UART? perhaps then edit the question to make this mor clear

Comment: I googled the arduino rx and tx pins and it's probably uart

Comment: You could always measure it with a DMM.

Comment: You should be aware that connecting a 3.3V logic signal to a device that expects a 5V signal may be unreliable. You may need a level shifter of some kind to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

For UART, the RX pin is always an input. There might be a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the board and possibly a series resistor, but this will depend on how the board is wired.

Answer (score 1):

For UART communication in MCUs, the transmitter keeps its TX line in HIGH level when idle. And yes, you have to convert the signal to a valid voltage level at RX pin of receiver UART.

Independently of your *Arduino* board: **initialize the UART and check the voltage at the RX pin with a multimeter**. This probe method is almost definitive and avoids reviewing board schematics and MCU datasheets.

In your case, *ESP32* (3.3V) TX-pin to *Arduino* (5V) RX-pin is not electrically dangerous, but review the logic threshold voltage levels (**VIH parameter for UART**) in the Arduino MCU datasheet in order to be sure that 3.3V level is rightly interpreted as HIGH in receiver UART.